# After Xampp install php files downloading when called

Tags: apache2, php

I recently installed xampp and when ever my html file calls a php script firefox downloads the script instead of running it. I have the php5 module installed and this is what my apache hhtpd.conf file looks like:

```
Alias /bitnami/ "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs"
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php4
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php4
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php5
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

first time trying to set up apache not really sure what is going on `enter code here`